# How to update attributes in map DynamoDB

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

I want to update attributes #name in #info but sometimes #info doesn't exist

```
table.update_item(
    Key={
        'id': '001'
    },
    UpdateExpression='SET #k = if_not_exists(#k, :i), #k.#ks = :kv',
    ExpressionAttributeNames={
        '#k': 'info',
        '#ks': 'name'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':i': {},
        ':kv': 'new_name'
    }
)
```

An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: Invalid UpdateExpression: Two document paths overlap with each other; must remove or rewrite one of these paths; path one: [info], path two: [info, name]

I want to check if #info exists. If not, create a new #info, if there is, update #name.

Answer (score 0):

Shortly: try to update the field assuming it exists, in case of failure, check that you got a validation exception due to the non existing field you are trying to update, and create it from the root level.

Otherwise, set the `info` field as an empty dict at entry creation time.

```
def udpateItemName(id, val):
    try:
        table.update_item(
            Key={
                'id': id
            },
            UpdateExpression='SET #k.#ks = :kv',
            ExpressionAttributeNames={
                '#k': 'info',
                '#ks': 'name',
            },
            ExpressionAttributeValues={
                ':kv': val
            }
        )
    }
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as ce:
        if ce.response['Error']['Code'] != 'ValidationException':
            # some further checks can be made on ['Error']['Message'] here to be sure 
            # that the error is due to non existing path
            raise ce
        table.update_item(
            Key={
                'id': id
            },
            UpdateExpression='SET #k = :kv',
            ExpressionAttributeNames={
                '#k': 'info'
            },
            ExpressionAttributeValues={
                ':kv': {"name": val}
            }
        )
    }
```